# I am facing problem in connection pgbouncer with postgresql in django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-database, pgbouncer, max-pooling

for the configuration of pgbouncer with postgresql in pgbouncer.ini file i have done

```
mydb= dbname=mydb host=**.**.**.** port=5432
listen_addr = *
listen_port = 6432
```

`unix_socket_dir = /var/run/postgresql`

then in userlist.txt file i have

`"usr" "pass"`

then in django settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default':
 {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'mydb', #its db name
    'USER':'usr', #it's my user name of database
    'PASSWORD': 'pass', #it's my password of database
    'HOST': 'localhost', #it's my host of database

 }
}
```

but when i started gunicorn server then in status it is giving me an error that
`Mar 20 07:35:27 testenv gunicorn[288076]: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "usr"`

I tried to configure pgbouncer with postgresql to solve the problem of max_connection_pooling but it is constantly giving the same error when i'm tried to start the gunicorn server.

I'm expecting to solve

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections`

Comment: Your django setting doesn't specify a port. So isn't it going to default to 5432, which is not where pgbouncer is listening?  What is listening on 5432?